# How do I vertically align text and a floated image in a table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

How can I vertically center `text on 1 line`? The text may change, so I want a generic solution.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rfECj/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="img.png"/>
            text on 2 lines text on 2 lines text on 2 lines
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="img.png"/>
            text on 2 lines text on 2 lines text on 2 lines
        </td>
        <td>
            <img src="img.png"/>
            text on 1 line
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
table img {
    margin: 4px 6px 0 6px;
    float: left;
}

table tr td {
    width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: Do the images need to be center-aligned as well?

Comment: @Jason yes, but their size do not change, so i can add margin/padding on images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only solution that comes in mind is use more TDs, one for the image, one for the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfECj/5/

Answer (score 0):

anything wrong with using `vertical-align: middle;`?

Answer (score -1):

Hard to tell if this is what you want from the question, but you could use `vertical-align`, which works on `td`s.

```
table tr td {
    width: 180px;
    border:1px solid red; //just to see it better
    vertical-align:middle;   // add this
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfECj/9/